# How to test ssh socks by curl

Tags: networking, ssh

Here are the steps that I did so far, and I adapted these steps to use on localhost to make debugging easier.

I have a user that have ssh access to localhost. So I run this:

```
ssh -D 7070 mysshuser@127.0.0.1
```

To test this I am using curl. So in another terminal (where I am connected with my regular user account not the ssh user account) tab I am running this:

```
curl -v --max-time 10 --proxy 127.0.0.1:7070 http://www.google.ca
```

In the command output I can see that the connection to the port 7070 was successful. However the page is not rendered (empty reply from server):

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.ca/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 7070 (#0)
> GET http://www.google.ca/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.ca
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Thank you

Comment: syntax should be curl -x socks5://localhost:8080 http://www.google.ca . Posted as you were posting your answer

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, you are right. I was writing the same thing with a slightly different but equivalent syntax

Comment: You should probably change the question as this is more about curl syntax then it is about the ssh tunnel as the tunnel is working .

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, done. thanks. You may post your comment as an answer so that I accept it.

Comment: No you are good thank you though

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the option of curl that should be used is socks5 instead of proxy.
So this works like a charm:

```
curl -v --max-time 10 --socks5 127.0.0.1:7070 http://www.google.ca
```

But I am still waiting for other feedback.

thanks